# Sierra won't install

Tags: macos, install

From my mac OS 10.8.5 I downloaded OS Sierra from app store. It said it was downloaded and the icon was in my apps folder. I clicked it, agreed, gave my password, but it wouldn't install.

Per advice from Mac Support, I dragged the download to trash, and did a new download (took 22 hours). However, that one will not install either. I tried restarts, holding keys down and everything suggested, but still nothing.
It's a mac mini 2013, OS 10.8.5. I gave the serial numbers to Mac Support over the phone and they said it should work.

Why will it not install?!

Comment: What model / age mac? It may not install if the specs are not correct.

Comment: It's a mac mini 2013, OS 10.8.5. I gave the serial numbers to Mac Support over the phone and they said it should work.

Comment: Do you have plenty of disk space available?

Comment: Way more than enough. I've only used 30 gb out of 500 gb capacity.

Comment: The 22-hour download is ridiculous too. Do you have hi-speed internet. I don't know if problems are related though.

Comment: Hi Dennis, welcome to Ask Different. :) Is it at all possible you could [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/295428/edit) your question to further explain what you mean by *but it wouldn't install*? For example, are you getting any error messages? Or, does it just do nothing at all? Or does your mouse pointer turn into a spinning beachball? Etc. Also, did the original time you downloaded Sierra take a long time too (or is this normal because you just have slow internet)?

Answer (score 1):

It is a 5 Gb file.

Find a place where you can download it in 1-2 hours (22 is not good).
Apple store can do it for you!
or at Starbuck coffee shop you can do it in about 2 hours :)

Also, Verify the downloaded file is correct.

Open a terminal window up (Applications -> Utilities -> Terminal) then type:
cd "/Applications/Install macOS Sierra.app/Contents/SharedSupport" with those double quotes.

then type in:

```
shasum InstallESD.dmg
```

and after a couple minutes it should return:
**139ef35e4af0da8286b2a3af326cb114d774f606**  InstallESD.dmg